# System.IO.File does not contain a definition for ReadAllBytes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I read image bytes with `File.ReadAllBytes()` when I develop an Android application with xamarin.forms. The code works well in debug mode. However, it throws an error

> System.IO.File does not contain a definition for ReadAllBytes

in release mode. I wonder why this happened? Can I fix it by changing some settings for visual studio? Or it is ok that I use other way to read image byte.

Comment: So this is a runtime error?

Comment: It's unclear, are you seeing this when you build the project, or when it's already running? Normally it should be a build error, but there is no obvious reason why it would change just because you altered the VS settings from debug to release.

Comment: I don't know exactly the meaning of 'runtime'. The code indeed build successfuly and the error appears when the app running.

Comment: Is your release build targeted differently from your debug build? For example, is the release build targeted to Web (webplayer?) and the debug build targeted to Windows?

Comment: It's an application for android.  I don't know if there is setting to change target in vs.

Comment: Runtime means "when the app is running"

Comment: Thanks @ADyson. I learned about Runtime.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Thanks for everyone. I have figured out the problem. So stupid I am that I configured wrong setting for release mode by accident.